# Accomplishing OR with a FOR loop

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
Script  Reco    Rating  Suggestion  Mood
Rel     Buy     Sell    BuyL        Sell
ITC     Sell    Sell    Sell        Sell
INFO    Sell    BuyN    Sell        Sell
TCS     Sell    Sell    Sell        Sell
```

I want to get the rows where they is string 'Buy' in the columns 'Reco' , 'Rating', 'Suggestion' or 'Mood'.

I am able to accomplish that with the code below

```
df[(df['Reco'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Rating'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Suggestion'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Mood'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True))]
```

However, the problem is that I have to type in the name of all columns except 'Script'. To avoid that, tried doing something like below

```
cols_to_include = df.columns[df.columns != 'Script']
df[(df[i].str.contains('Buy') for i in cols_to_include)]
```

This does not work & that is because

```
(df['Reco'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Rating'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Suggestion'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True) | df['Mood'].str.contains('Buy', regex=True))
```

returns

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Whereas

```
[df[i].str.contains('Buy') for i in cols_to_include]
```

Returns

```
[0     True
 1    False
 2    False
 3    False
 Name: Reco, dtype: bool, 0    False
 1    False
 2     True
 3    False
 Name: Rating, dtype: bool, 0     True
 1    False
 2    False
 3    False
 Name: Suggestion, dtype: bool, 0    False
 1    False
 2    False
 3    False
 Name: Mood, dtype: bool]
```

How to make `[df[i].str.contains('Buy') for i in cols_to_include]` return the values as below?

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**PS:**
I am aware that can accomplish by output as below. But i am looking for a solution using `for` loop.

```
cols_to_include = df.columns[df.columns != 'Script']
a = df[cols_to_include].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
df[a.str.contains('BUY', regex=True)]
```

Comment: `|` should be `or`.

Comment: @Barmar Not in pandas indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out 'Script' and then use an apply function to check for the desired string.

```
df.loc[df[[e for e in df.columns if e!='Script']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Buy')).any(1)]

Script  Reco    Rating  Suggestion  Mood
0   Rel     Buy     Sell    BuyL    Sell
2   INFO    Sell    BuyN    Sell    Sell
```

Answer (score 2):

You could creat boolean mask using `stack` and `any`

```
m = df.drop('Script',1).stack().str.contains('Buy').any(level=0)

Out[1021]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Next, using it to slice as you want

```
df[m]

Out[1022]:
  Script  Reco Rating Suggestion  Mood
0    Rel   Buy   Sell       BuyL  Sell
2   INFO  Sell   BuyN       Sell  Sell
```

Comment: Thanks. One more way of doing it (without using as for loop)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to apply the string-contains check element-wise, and then aggregate the results using `.any` afterwards. Hence:

`df[cols_to_include].applymap(lambda x: 'Buy' in x).any(axis=1)`

Comment: This does not work. this result in stating if every column "['Reco', 'Rating', 'Suggestion', 'Mood']" has the value Buy or not. What i am trying to do is row wise.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the axis argument. Try it now.